# Storing a variable from a try statement

Tags: python, api

I have program that is calling into an API every 60 seconds and storing the data. The program is running on a cellular modem that is using Python 2.6. What I'm trying to do is have variables StartTimeConv and EndTimeConv from the try statement stored so that if the try statement fails the except statement can reference them. I've had them declared outside of the try statement, but that it generated a "referenced before assignment" error. What I'm ultimately trying to accomplish with this is if there's a cell signal issue or the API service isn't reachable, the start & stop times can still be referenced and the digital io triggers can still function.

```
def Client():
threading.Timer(60, Client).start()
# Request Session ID
request = urllib2.Request(url)
b64auth = base64.standard_b64encode("%s:%s" % (username,password))
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % b64auth)
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)    

# Parse and store Session ID
tree = ET.parse(result)
xml_data = tree.getroot()
sessionid = xml_data[1].text    

# Dispatch Event Request
url1 = "SiteURL".format(sessionid)
request1 = urllib2.Request(url1)
result1 = urllib2.urlopen(request1)
# Read and store sys time
sys_time = time.localtime()
# Convert Sys time to datetime object
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(sys_time))

# Parse and store Dispatch Event, start and stop time
try:
    tree1 = ET.parse(result1)
    xml_data1 = tree1.getroot()
    dispatchEvent = xml_data1[0][0][2].text
    EventStartTime = xml_data1[0][0][14].text
    EventEndTime = xml_data1[0][0][1].text
    #Convert string time to datetime object
    StartTimeConv = datetime.strptime(xml_data1[0][0][14].text, "%a %B %d, %Y %H:%M")
    EndTimeConv = datetime.strptime(xml_data1[0][0][1].text, "%a %B %d, %Y %H:%M")
    print(dispatchEvent)
    print(StartTimeConv)
    print(EndTimeConv)
    print(dt)
except:
    print("No Event")
    pass
else:
    if dispatchEvent is not None and dt >= StartTimeConv:
        set_digital_io('D0', 'on')
    elif dispatchEvent is not None and dt <= EndTimeConv:
        set_digital_io('D0', 'off')
    else:
        set_digital_io('D0', 'off')
```

Comment: What do you mean by *that didn't work*?

Comment: Explain "didn't work". What happens, what should happen?

Comment: The *else* block is only entered if no exceptions were raised (in the try/except block) in which case both StartTimeConv and EndTimeConv will be available. Unless this is a pre-Python 3 issue

Comment: Having the StartTimeConv & EndTimeConv variables outside of the try/except statement caused a "referenced before assignment" error.

Comment: You probably tried to use them *after* the `try` statement when an exception was raised before you defined them.

Comment: Set them to e. g. "None" before the try-block and check them for "None" before using them otherwise in the else-block.

Comment: Better yet, either define the variables *after* the `try` completes successfully, and don't ignore the exception if your code isn't actually ready to continue after it happens. (There is way too much code in your `try` block, and you shouldn't be catching exceptions that you aren't ready to actually handle. Printing "No Event" is not a handler for the vast majority of the exceptions that might occur.)